# Session management with the new Google identity services web api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-signin

I've just begun work on a new web application and I wanted to implement account creation/logins using google's OAuth flow. I noticed that they're discontinuing the API most people are using.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.
I'm trying to understand how the flow for then new API (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) works.

From what I've tried, that API just responds with a single access token, which is fine for the 15 minutes it's valid for, but I don't want my users to have to go through the login process every time they revisit the site. There doesn't seem to be a method in the API for refreshing the access token without the user having to be involved.

I feel like I'm missing a step because this doesn't feel like a replacement for the existing API at all.

Basically I'm asking if this new API has any session management capabilities. If it doesn't should I just use the deprecated API for now?

Answer (score 2):

To get an overview of what is taking place during sign-in, imho it would be worth the five minutes or less it takes to read [How it works](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview#how_it_works) to build a high level understanding of what's going on.

In answer to your specific questions:

Access tokens are no longer used, and neither are refresh tokens. A JWT ID token is shared instead. JWTs do not expire, but are signed and you'll want to validate them.  The [token response](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#token_response) section of the migration guide has more detail on the switch to JWT's.

For session state you'll want to be aware that there are two session states 1) between the user and their Google account 2) the user and your app. The two are independent. The previous library included some helper functions to help you look at 1, but one side-effect was it made the distinction between 1 & 2 hazy and unclear. [Session state and Listeners](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#session_state_and_listeners) has more.

Comment: If I bring the JWT that's returned from the API, it has an expiration date of an hour.
Surely this will become invalid after that, no?

Comment: Yes, the JWT will expire. The JWT is signed and you can/should validate that it is signed by Google and valid.  The JWT simply says WHO the user is--from a trusted source. That's it.  Just to be certain it's clear; the JWT and it's expiration should NOT be used to infer if a user is currently signed into their Google Account or not. Signed in status to your app should be tracked and managed independently of the user having an active session with Google as well.